# How to test file.watch on localhost?

Tags: testing, google-drive-api

I am displaying the contents of a folder in my AngularJS front-end (with Rails back-end). I want to watch the folder for any changes, such as new file, deleted file.

I obviously want to test the app on my localhost before deploying to a server, but I am not able to add localhost as an allowed domain in the apis console.

How can I set-up file.watch for testing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to test push notifications without a verified domain, it's why we cant push confidential information to untrusted endpoints. I'd recommend you to buy/use a test domain/sub-domain for testing.

Comment: Or, you can try Push Notifications Playground: https://pushnotificationsplayground.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

there's [portly.co](https://portly.co/)

worke's really nice , you can verify the domain with google site verification, and add it as a push domain.